# SQLite3 Create Table Unexpected "(" Error

Tags: sql, sqlite, ubuntu-18.04

### Set up

Ubuntu 18.04 on Google VM

### Objective

I'm trying to create a for loop to create multiple tables based on my list of clients

### Issue

I can create a table just fine if I run

```
user@sql-server:~$ sqlite3 mydatabase.db
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table client (Date integer, cheese integer, id1 integer, id2 integer, id3 integer, id4 integer, id5 integer, id6 integer, id7 integer, id8 integer, id9 integer, id10 integer, id11 integer, id12 integer, id13 integer, id14 integer, id15 integer, id16 integer, id17 integer, id18 integer, id19 integer, id20 integer);
sqlite> .tables
client  test
```

but when I try to create a script "test.sh" like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

sqlite3 adloox.db create table test2 (test2 string, testno2 integer);

exit
```

I get the following error:

```
user@sql-server:~$ sh -x test.sh
+ set -eu
test.sh: 5: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I can see if I input `sqlite3 adloox.db .tables` I can get a response from the terminal, so I believe I need to have this on one line as opposed to across multiple lines in my script, as it will then request the manual input. But I find it strange that the error I get relates to the "(" as there I don't see what the difference is. Can someone confirm what I'm missing with how what I'm doing in the script differs from the manual input? I've tried googling for an answer but everything I find keeps pointing to manual inputs. Appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: I haven't tested this on your same environment, but does the script have access to sqlite either by permissions or the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add quotes around your sqlite3 command this way :

```
sqlite3 adloox.db 'create table test2 (test2 string, testno2 integer);'
```

Comment: @mathiteu it's always the simple things... Thanks, confirming it worked and will accept the answer once I'm not blocked by the timer